# Java Word Search Puzzle in Char Array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, methods

I am working on a method to find a word on a word puzzle grid.

The letters are put in a matrix. The method should print out the row and column the first letter of the word was found at and the direction (n, s, e, w, ne, nw, se, sw) that the pattern goes in.

The method I have currently is:

```
public static String wordSearch(int r, int c, String letters, String search){
  int x[] = { -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 };
  int y[] = { -1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1 };
  char [][] puzzle = new char [r][c];
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < r; i++){
     for (int j = 0; j < c; j++){
        puzzle[i][j] = letters.charAt(count);
        count++;
     }
  }
  int length = search.length();
  for (int dir = 0; dir < 8; dir++)
  {
     int k;
     int rd = r + x[dir]; 
     int cd = c + y[dir];

     for (k = 1; k < length; k++)
     {
        rd += x[dir]; 
        cd += y[dir];
     }
     if (k == length)
        return rd+ ", "+cd;
  }
  return "Not found";}
```

The problem is finding out how to return the direction the pattern goes in along with the first letter of the word (It only passed one test case). However, I am certain that the method can tell if the word is in the grid or not.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way is to define a class that captures all the data you want to return. For example:

```
public class Result {
    int row;
    int col;
    int direction;
}
```

Then, if you find the search word, create a new instance of this class and return it. If the search word is not found, just return `null`. Note that you'll have to change the return type of your method from `String` to `Result`.

I'm not going to comment about the detection logic of your current code, other than to note that it doesn't correctly test for anything. It also risks throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you aren't checking whether you are running off the edges of the puzzle.

Alternatively, you can continue encoding everything as a `String` and return a three-element string: `return rd + ", " + rc + ", " + dir;`.